# Capturing a SQL INSERT statement with additional values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have an INSERT statement in my vb.net application. Something along the way of...

```
 SQL = " Insert into tableA (Value1, Value2, Value3) Values (Mark1, City2, State3) "
```

What I'm trying to do is pass this into a function that will actually insert the SQL statement. I am trying to insert a copy of this sql statement in a LOG table.

```
 Public Function (InsertSQL as String) As Boolean
 nSql = "INSERT INTO tblSQLLOG ( InsertSQL, Date, User) VALUES ( "
 nSql += "'" & InsertSQL + "', "
 nSql += "'" & Now() & "', "
 nSql += CStr(userName) + ") "

 cmd = New SqlCommand(nSql, conn)
 End Function
```

So now if i check my nSQL it looks something like....

```
Insert into tblSQLLOG (insert sql, date,user) values ('insert Insert into tableA (Value1, Value2, Value3) Values ('Mark1', 'City2', 'State3')','11/30/2016 8:46:41 AM', 'Bobby')
```

In this insert statement I'm gettig an error near Value1 - I don't know what i'm doing wrong.  Everything looks fine to me.

Comment: You should use a parameter

Comment: Always use SQL Parameters.  The log can use `cmd.CommandText`

Comment: Are you trying to insert on both tables `tableA` and `tblSQLLOG`?

Comment: @Viki888 - I'm trying to insert a insert statement. Basically I need to insert into tblSQLLOG - the insert into tableA statement - so in case of Debug error user might see I can see the full statement and see where the error was

Comment: if somene has a reason to downvote i'm happy to hear - I provider a clear example, defined what my issue was - and shown exactly what i've done. Just because i do it a different way should in no way define whether this question deserves a downvote. I explained to a few regulars that I would use parameters if the applicatino was written by me. It was written by others and I have to include additional stuff in that same way that they've done. And this is how they've done it. Every sql is concatenated -good or bad? Not my issue. I follow their suit.

Comment: Keep in mind SO posts are for the ages. Concatenating SQL is wrong, not just a different way (and results in oddball things like your *Inserting apostrophe strings into sql server* question)     Any peculiar restraints you have do not make it a good idea to do SQL that way.  The DV is probably meant to signal that - the question is not useful to others.  Not sure thats why, just guessing.

Comment: _Not my issue. I follow their suit_ not a good sign. Based on your code sample, you creating query, command by yourself(not some global helper class). So you have good possibility write proper sql insertion code with parameters, `using` keyword for connection and commands. Why not. After you add/change some code it becomes **yours**, even if you changed only one line - whole file becomes yours

Comment: Having learned that the old code has serious flaws (storing `O'Hare` as `O''Hare` so the SQL can be concatenated *is* a serious flaw), you may want to explain to TPTB  that the code base has serious issues and  does not conform to best practices for the 21st Century.  "They" need to know. Additionally maintenance could be reduced going forward using new techniques - it just is not that tedious or torturous to compose SQL, update DB from multiple forms etc.  It may not be too late

Comment: @plutonix - I completely agree. I've already suggested parametizing everything. There are deadlines to follow but as soon as it meets the standards in terms of functionality - it will be fixed. There's too much stuff to update (that's the main issue) many many SQL statements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you should use parameters.  that said the issue is that you have single quotes within the the string.  Notice the Replace() for InsertSQL

```
Public Function (InsertSQL as String) As Boolean
 nSql = "INSERT INTO tblSQLLOG ( InsertSQL, Date, User) VALUES ( "
 nSql += "'" & Replace(InsertSQL,"'","''") + "', "
 nSql += "'" & Now() & "', "
 nSql += CStr(userName) + ") "

 cmd = New SqlCommand(nSql, conn)
 End Function
```

Comment: This might cause another error on datetime (client and server might be using different cultures). Use parameters instead.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Parameters is the way to go.  That's why I upvoted your answer.  I was just illustrating what was causing the error.

Comment: Yes, I mean the proposed one is also prone to error. Just replacing single quotes wouldn't help. There might be double quote(s) in string - ie: 4" screw. If you work that one around too, then comes the BIGGER SQL injection attack. IOW I would be always against suggestions other than using parameters.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Again, I am not disagreeing with you.  The replace would indeed fix his error, and the double quotes would not be an issue here.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - this works. The problem I'm always seeing is I provide a specific example with a specific issue and JOHN is one of the only ones that gives me a solution to MY problem. I understand that parameters prevent sql injection and take care of other issues. I ask a question and he provides a solution to that specific issue. If you've downvoted it I ask that you change it please because all he did is SOLVE my issue.

Comment: @Bobski Thanks for the support.  I figured you needed a quick fix.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti you got it

Comment: @Bobski  Cheers  :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, because you have accepted answer it will be nice if you add the solution with parameters for future readers. Because main reason of OPs problem was - **not used parameters**. If parameters was used in the first place - there wasn't such a problem.

Comment: @Bobski, I tried to upvote back before and it didn't work. I still don't agree with the suggestion but that is another matter. Let be it. Pity you asked how to jump out of the window and got a chair as a solution.

Comment: @Bobski with this solution your problem wasn't solved - ti was delayed for later times with bigger impact. Note - for removing downvote somebody need to edit answer.

Comment: @CetinBasoz -LOL i like that. Yes but all in all that's what I needed

Comment: @fabio - why don't you answer this question to the most proper way of doing it and i'll mark it as answer!

Comment: @Bobski he didn't want to duplicate mine:)

Answer (score 3):

You are doing one BIG thing wrong and that is, you are not using parameters.

```vb
Public Function FuncName (InsertSQL as String) As Boolean
 nSql = <sql>INSERT INTO tblSQLLOG 
   ( InsertSQL, [Date], [User]) 
   VALUES 
   ( @InsertSQL, @Date, @User)
 </sql>

 cmd = New SqlCommand(nSql, conn)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InsertSQL", InsertSQL)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", CStr(userName))

 ' then what? you would use cmd and return true or false

 End Function
```

PS: Also check auditing in SQL server.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` is "evil". ADO.NET will create parameters dynamically and query plan for the query will be compiled every time value changes

Comment: Fabio, not exactly. The parameters would be created only once, then you can change the Value N times. The query plan OTOH depends on the SQL which is parametric and fixed.

Comment: Not agree about query plan. For `AddWithValue("@One", "test")` will be generated query with parameter `VARCHAR4(4)`. For AddWithValue("@One", "testtest")` will be generated query with parameter `VARCHAR(8)`. Sql server will compile two different query plans

Comment: @Fabio, I am not sure about that, but didn't try explicitly. You may be right. One could do it as AddWithValue("@pname", "".PadRight(100)) and then set the value as he wishes. In a loop AddWithValue would be used initially. If need to think about such optimization, then probably I would have an SP instead or a CLR function. I wouldn't even write something like this on client side.

Comment: Will be enough to create parameter explicitly: `new SqlParameter With { .ParameterName = "@One", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Size = 8};`

Comment: That is what I meant :) .AddWithValue("@one", "".PadRigth(8)).Value = "someval"; is a syntactic sugar. OK I agree with you.